# GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView) throws a NullReference exception

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

After building C# WebApps, I need to build a Windows Apps with WINUI 3 in VS2022 and I am struggling with a small item. My apologies upfront for this, but I am replicating the [Simple Photo Editor Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/simple-photo-viewer-winui3?tabs=cs) from Microsoft Learn and I seem to have hit a snag. When calling the `var thumbnail = ImageFile.GethumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView)`, thumbnail remains null.
When changing to `ThumbnailMode.DocumentsView` returns a low-res picture (so that works!).

When loading the full picture with `GetImageSourceAsync` the picture load fine (so that works too!).

I am obviouosly missing something, but what? Thank you for some pointers.

My `ImageFileInfo.cs` is:

```
public class ImageFileInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ImageFileInfo(ImageProperties properties, StorageFile imageFile, string name, string type) 
    { 
        ImageProperties = properties;
        ImageName = name;
        ImageFileType = type;
        ImageFile = imageFile;
        var rating = (int)properties.Rating;
        var random = new Random();
        ImageRating = rating == 0 ? random.Next(1, 5) : rating;
    }
    public StorageFile ImageFile { get;}
    public ImageProperties ImageProperties { get;}

    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageSourceAsync()
    {
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await ImageFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            //create a bitmap to be the image source
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);

            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }

    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageThumbnailAsync()
    {
        var thumbnail = await ImageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView); //ImageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView);
        // Create a bitmap to be the image source
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(thumbnail);
        thumbnail.Dispose();

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

My `MainWindow.xaml.cs` is:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageFileInfo> Images { get; }= new ObservableCollection<ImageFileInfo>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        GetItemsAsync();
    }

    private async Task GetItemsAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFolder picturesFolder = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets\\Samples");

        var result = picturesFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(new QueryOptions());

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> imageFiles = await result.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach(StorageFile file in imageFiles)
        {
            Images.Add(await LoadImageInfoAsync(file));
        }
        ImageGridView.ItemsSource = Images;

    }

    public async static Task<ImageFileInfo> LoadImageInfoAsync(StorageFile file)
    {
        var properties = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
        ImageFileInfo info = new(properties, file, file.DisplayName, file.DisplayType);

        return info;
    }


private void ImageGridView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.InRecycleQueue)
    {
        var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
        var image = templateRoot.FindName("ItemImage") as Image;
        image.Source = null;
       
    }
    if(args.Phase == 0)
    {
        args.RegisterUpdateCallback(ShowImage);
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}

private async void ShowImage(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Phase == 1)
    {
        var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
        var image = templateRoot.FindName("ItemImage") as Image;
        var item = args.Item as ImageFileInfo;

            image.Source = await item.GetImageThumbnailAsync();   
    }
}
}
```

}

Comment: Tested this https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/PhotoEditor/cs-winui and it works fine for me. Per doc, null is expected *"it returns a StorageItemThumbnail that represents the thumbnail image or null if there is no thumbnail image associated with the file."* but null is different from NullReferenceException of your title

Comment: I tried exactly the same example and I got the NullException Error when debugging. Did you get the pictures loaded? I expect that the method creates the thumbnail from the original picture. Is that correct? The documentation appears ambiguous.

Comment: Pull from git, run, everything works fine pictures are loaded https://i.imgur.com/8F1plR2.png (Windows 10 x64)

Comment: Did exactly that. Even tried it on different computers, but with the same problem. I now suspect it has something to do with my VS2022 configuration or the fact that everything is stored on a OneDrive Folder (synced). Thanks for your trouble.

Comment: I can reproduce for the first time, and I found `10.jpg` picture always returns null thumbnail. After deleting `10.jpg` the *PhotoEditor* failed to run although I restored it later. So, I deleted the whole project and download it again. Now the *PhotoEditor* runs well...

Comment: Sounds like a thumbnail cache issue, try to clear your thumbnails (using Disk Cleanup as admin is the best way) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-can-i-delete-old-thumbnail-data-on-my-computer/911a17eb-bc4d-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: Did that and it works. Thank you for your great help

Comment: I have similar issue, and realized that files stored on network drive do not work, while local files do.. mmm